# PSQL function cannot escaping quotes

Tags: postgresql, escaping, plpgsql, psql, greenplum

i have query like below. to analyze and compare the count of row the same table on different server. it worked as expected but will face a problem if there are any table name with mixed lower and upper case like : 'stg.my_table_OTHER'.

it worked if i add quotes like stg."my_table_OTHER". but it doesnt seems to work on function. already tried to escape with '\"stg.my_table_OTHER\"' but still no luck.

please find below my query.

regards,
rian

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dwh.sync_update_analyze(schemaname varchar, tablename varchar)
        RETURNS integer AS $body$
        DECLARE

            passedSrc boolean;
            passedTgt boolean;
            rowcount bigint;                                                                                                  
            tgtcount bigint;
            query text; 
        BEGIN
            SELECT EXISTS (                                                                                                   
                    SELECT 1                                                                                                       
                    FROM   pg_catalog.pg_class c                                                                                   
                    JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace                                                     
                    WHERE  n.nspname = $1                                                                                          
                    AND    c.relname = $2                                                                                          
                    AND    c.relkind = 'r'    -- only tables                                                                       
            ) into passedSrc;

            passedTgt = ops.runcmd('psql -h 666.66.6.666 -Atc "SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace WHERE n.nspname = ''' || schemaname || ''' AND c.relname = ''' || tablename || ''' AND c.relkind = ''r'');"');



            IF passedSrc = 't' and passedTgt = 't' THEN

            query = ops.runcmd('psql -h 666.66.6.666 -Atc "ANALYZE ' || schemaname || '.' || tablename || ';"'); 

                tgtcount = ops.runcmd('psql -h 666.66.6.666 -Atc "select count(*) from ' || schemaname || '.' || tablename || ';"'); 
                EXECUTE '(select count(1) from ' || quote_ident($1) || '.' || quote_ident($2) || ')' INTO rowcount;               
                         query := 'UPDATE dwh.table_list_2018 SET                                                                  
                         move_data_to_dca = ''D'',                                                                                 
                         row_count = '|| rowcount || ',
                         target_cnt = '|| tgtcount ||'
                         WHERE schema = ''' || $1 || ''' and table_name = ''' || $2 || '''';          
                         EXECUTE query;

            ELSE                                                                                                           
                         query := 'UPDATE dwh.table_list_2018 SET                                                                  
                         move_data_to_dca = ''D'',                                                                                 
                         purge_table = ''Y'',
                         backup_location = ''table maybe purge on source or relation doesnt exists''                                                                                       
                         WHERE schema = ''' || $1 || ''' and table_name = ''' || $2 || '''';          
                         EXECUTE query;                                                                                            

           END IF; 

                 return 0;

                    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
                 query := 'UPDATE dwh.table_list_2018 SET                                                                  
             move_data_to_dca = ''D'',                                                                                 
             purge_table = ''Y'',
             backup_location = ''table maybe purge on source or relation doesnt exists''                                                                                
             WHERE schema = ''' || $1 || ''' and table_name = ''' || $2 || '''';          
             EXECUTE query; 
             RETURN 1;


        END
        $body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

the error throws at this part

```
 tgtcount = ops.runcmd('psql -h 666.66.6.666 -Atc "select count(*) from ' || schemaname || '.' || tablename || ';"');
```

when i eedit into

```
 tgtcount = ops.runcmd('psql -h 666.66.6.666 -Atc "select count(*) from ' || schemaname || '.\"' || tablename || '\";"');
```

it throws

```
 HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for escapes, e.g., E'\r\n'
 INT:  Use the escape string syntax for escapes, e.g., E'\r\n'.
 QUERY:  SELECT  ops.runcmd('psql -h 666.66.6.666 -Atc "select count(*) from ' ||  $1  || '.\"' ||  $2  || '\";"')
 CONTEXT:  SQL statement in PL/PgSQL function "sync_update_analyze1" near line 26
 WARNING:  nonstandard use of escape in a string literal
```

just for the information. im using

```
 "PostgreSQL 8.2.15 (Greenplum Database 4.3.18.0 build 1) on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.4.2 compiled on Nov 22 2017 18:54:31"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about greenplum, but if it behaves like PostgreSQL, I'd try like this:

```
tgtcount := ops.runcmd(
               'psql -h 666.66.6.666 -Atc ''select count(*) from '
               || quote_ident(schemaname) || '.'
               || quote_ident(tablename) || ';'''
            );
```

That way you use single quotes for the SQL statement so that there is no conflict with the double quotes that `quote_ident` might add.

Comment: Hi Albe. thanks for the response. i tried it and yes it does put the double quotes but it lowered the case. and still throw error the intended table doesn't exists.

Comment: Well, it works in PostgreSQL. Consider this `DO` statement: `DO $$DECLARE s text := 'Schema'; t text := 'Table'; BEGIN RAISE NOTICE '%', 'psql -h 666.66.6.666 -Atc ''select count(*) from ' || quote_ident(s) || '.' || quote_ident(t) || ';'''; END;$$;` The result is: `NOTICE:  psql -h 666.66.6.666 -Atc 'select count(*) from "Schema"."Table";'` Not sure what is wrong on your side, but then I don't know what `ops.runcms` does exactly.

Comment: assigning into variables and quote_ident do the trick. it works now. thanks man!

Comment: @ryanfauzi: If you have your answer, consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/169168).